# A generalization of Feit–Thompson conjecture, for square-free integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, conjectures, divisors-multiples

I asked the following question with my account that I have for these sites Mathematics Stack Exchange and MathOverflow. The bounty that I offered in MSE  expired without answers. The post that I refer is this [*MSE 3591614*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591614/a-generalization-of-feit-thompson-conjecture-for-square-free-integers) (March, 23th 2020). See the useful comments that were added in MSE.

Few weeks ago I wondered about if the following conjecture is in the literature or well if it is possible to find a counterexample. I evoke a generalization of a well-known conjecture, I mean the [*Feit–Thompson conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_conjecture) from Wikipedia.

An integer $n>1$ is square-free or squarefree if has no repeated prime factors. For example $n=15$ is squarefree, while than $12$ has repeated prime factors.

**Conjecture.** *There are no distinct square-free integers* $p$ *and* $q$ *(both greater than* $1$*) with* $\gcd(p,q)=1$ *such that* $\frac{p^q-1}{p-1}$ *divides* $\frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$.

> **Question.** What work can be done about the veracity of this conjecture? Since Feit–Thompson conjecture seems a particular case of this, then I'm asking if previous conjecture is in the literature, or well if you've some approach or heuristic about the **Conjecture** or well if it is possible to find a counterexample. **Many thanks.**

I wrote a Pari/GP program and I've tested the **Conjecture**, let's say for the segments of integers $2\leq p,q\leq 2000$. I hope that there were not mistakes and this post is interesting.

### References:

[1] Feit, W. and Thompson, J. G., *A Solvability Criterion for Finite Groups and Some Consequences*, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA 48, 968-970, (1962).

Comment: To the moderator team of MO/MSE, as soon there is feedback about if this question is interesting for MathOverflow, feel free to handle the MSE 3591614 question as you consider it is right (I say this since I never had a cross-posted question).

Comment: Maybe this could be reduced to the original Feit-Thompson conjecture considering that, writing the set of prime factors of $p$ as $p_i$ and the set of prime factors of $q$ as $q_j$ one has $(p_i,q_j)=1$. The only idea I have so far is to consider automorphisms of the rings of $p$-adic and $q$-adic integers.

Comment: More precisely, maybe we can try to prove that FTC is equivalent to $p\neq q\Longleftrightarrow Aut(Z_{p})\cap Aut(Z_{q})=\{e\}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your ideas and attention. My abstract algebra isn't the best @SylvainJULIEN

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN There are (at least) two issues with this. First of all, how do you want to take an intersection of automorphism groups of *distinct rings*? Second, $\mathbb Z_p$ always has a trivial automorphism group, so your equivalence doesn't hold since the intersection is also trivial for $p=q$.

Comment: (1/2) Since few months ago my belief is that there exists a "nice" interpretation of the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$ that "moves rectangles to rectangles in a special way" (I can not explain better my belief). I consider rectangles $a\times b$ with $a\geq 1$ and for integers $a<b$ formed by identical unitary squares $1\times 1$. See also the recent post MathOverflow **357376** with title *Another kind of primality related to tessellations by polygons*, which inspires in my opinion that $\sigma(\text{rectangle})=\text{ a convex}$ with the exception of the sequence *A023194* from the

Comment: (2/2) OEIS that is precisely the integers $n\geq 2$ such that $\sigma(n)=\text{ a prime}$. Finally see the comment in previous *A023194* by Thomas Ordowski (Nov 18 2017). I edit these comments with the intention if you @Wojowu or the user in commments want to think about it (my belief is that maybe it is potentially related to compositions of the sum of divisors function with, in a way that I don't know, the Dedekind psi function or the Euler's totient function, and related to constructible polygons with compass and straightedge, Fermat primes and Mersenne primes). I hope don't disturb.

Comment: I write this comment for your attention @SylvainJULIEN in this and previous comments if you want to think about the previous thread of comments. Additionally I believe that the following conjecture is true: *If an integer* $n\geq 2$ *satisfies* $\sigma(\sigma(n))=1+\frac{n\operatorname{rad}(n)-1}{\operatorname{rad}(n)-1}$, *then its sum of divisors* $\sigma(n)$ *is a prime number* (here $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the product of distinct primes dividing $n$).  With the help of Ordowski's claim it is easy to check that each term of the sequence *A023194* satisfies previous equation. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get your point right now but I'll try to think of it and let you know.

Comment: just reaching out to you when I read you are losing your internet access from home; we will miss you as a frequent contributor!

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate this community of users very much @CarloBeenakker , I hope your colleagues (professors) and users of this website are in good health.

Comment: @Wojowu please I've edited a (my last on MathOverflow) comment in the post with identificator **407529** , can you think about it? Many thanks.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN please I've edited a (my last on MathOverflow) comment in the post related with an attempt to get an interpretation of the sum of divisors function, prime numbers and chirality. It is the post with identificator **407529** , can you think about it? Many thanks.